# Javascript loop array objects N times?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I am currently attempting to loop through an array of objects n times, but I am having trouble with the logic. This is my current loop:

```
arrayObj.forEach(carName => console.log("looped"));
```

The array of object is named `arrayObj` where `carName` is a property of each object. I want to perform this forEach n times, but I can't get something like this to work in the scenario:

```
var times = 10;
for(var i=0; i < times; i++){
    doSomething();
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: replace `doSomething();` with the forEach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 2 loops, so you can do something like this

```
let test = [{name:'katty'},{name:'don'},{name:'michael'}]

for(let i = 0 ;i < 10;i++) {
  test.forEach(t => {
    console.log(t);
  })
}
```